# Notify user if Firebase database id exists

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if an id already exists before inserting it (prevent updating an already existing id).
This is the code I have so far:

```
database.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it's OK.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

The problem is that, when the id does not exists, it shows both toasts. But, when it does exist, it only shows the "it exists." one.

How can I show the "it exists." toast only when the id exists / How can I prevent the "it exist." toast from showing when the id doesn't exist?

EDIT:

Firebase database structure:

```
-DATABASE
    -ID
        -NAME
        -DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Can you share firebase db structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do this:

```
database.child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it's OK.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Since the `valueeventListener` will iterate through all the child(id) thus you will get both `Toast` the one for exists and for does not exists.

Use the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` then it will only iterate in the id that you specify before.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
database.child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.getValue()!=null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it's OK.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your `addValueEventListener` Method with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` .

Because possibly `addValueEventListener` will be called twice due to change in data Thats the reason it first shows Exist and than not Exist for same id.

For `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` firebase states that it supposed to:

> Read Data Once.
>
> In some cases it may be useful for a callback to be called once and
>   then immediately removed. We've created a helper function to make this
>   easy: